# Cannot pick up an object in Unity game

Tags: unity

I have a `PickupTarget` object in front of my `FirstPersonCharacter` which is used for 'holding' picked up object. Somehow, it doesn't work; when I click on the object (`Axe`) it just stays on the ground.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PickUp : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform target;

    void Update () {

    }

    void onMouseDown() {
        this.transform.position = target.position;
        this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find ("FirstPersonCharacter").transform;
    }

    void onMouseUp() {
        this.transform.parent = null;
    }
}
```

I have added `PickupTarget` as a `target` of script in `Axe` object:

[image: target]

This is the structure of my `Axe` object.

[image: Axe object]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onMouseDown()` is just a random function. You aren't calling it from anywhere in your code and Unity won't call it because it's not [the MonoBehaviour event method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html).

You want `OnMouseDown()`.

Same goes for your `onMouseUp()`: `OnMouseUp()`

Capitalization matters.

Also make sure that the script the GameObject is attached to has its own Collider component as well.

Comment: +1 Also as a note, I believe in the latest Unity downloads, functions are required to be capitalised at the start.

Comment: @cmprogram I am not so sure about that. I've got this function `void callbackMethod(Message msg)` in a 2017.2 project right now.

Comment: Edit: It works with the cube (`GameObject > 3D Object > Cube`), but still doesn't work with the `Axe` object.

Comment: @Nikola Does your axe have a collider? (Attached to the same GO as the script).

Comment: @Draco18s I have added `Box Collider` as a component of `Axe` object and it works now, thanks!

Comment: @Nikola Edited my answer to include that, too. :)